# How do you load text from a file in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, vb6

I have this code in Visual Basic that loads text from a file. I need to translate it into Delphi, but can't figure out how.

```
Open txtFile.Text For Binary As #1
file = Space(LOF(1))
Get #1, , file
Close #1
```

How do I get this code to work in Delphi?

Answer (score 7):

If your Delphi is not too old, you can do this:

```
uses IOUtils;
...
S := TFile.ReadAllText('MyFileName.txt');
```

<sub>Don't invent your own solutions when the RTL provides something that's already good enough!</sub>

Answer (score 6):

VB's [`LOF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtz29k5z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) returns a long integer that represents the length of a file. In this case, it's being used to allocate a string that is `LOF` spaces in size, and `LOF()` is returning the length of whatever filename is in `txtFile.Text` (which is probably an edit control).

Delphi doesn't need such techniques to simply load a text file into memory.  The roughly equivalent code in Delphi if you're just wanting to get the file contents into a string:

```
function LoadTextFromFile(const FileName: string): string;
var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  Result := '';
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    Result := SL.Text;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Using it:

```
var
  MyText: string;
begin
  MyText := LoadTextFromFile('C:\Temp\MyFile.txt');
  // Do something with text
end;
```

It's even easier if you want to display the text for the user - just drop a `TEdit`,  `TMemo` and a `TButton` on your form, double-click the button to create an `OnClick` event, and use code like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(Edit1.Text);
end;
```

For the purists out there, this is a close *literal* equivalent:

```
function GetStringFromFile(const FileName: string): AnsiString;
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result := '';
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    MS.LoadFromFile('D:\Temp\TestText.txt');
    SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(MS.Memory), MS.Size);
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That is not strictly equivalent. `TStringList.LoadFromFile()` parses the file data into an array of `String` values, and then `TStringList.Text` reformats that array into a single `String`. At best, you might end up changing the characters used for line breaks if the original file used different line breaks than what `TStringList` uses. At worse, you might corrupt the data altogether if the file is not parsed correctly. The direct equivalent of the VB code would be to retrieve the file size, allocate an `AnsiString` of that length, and then read the raw file data directly into it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: And "not strictly equivalent" is exactly why I said "rough equivalent". Since there's no indication of how the string is used afterward, it's difficult to be more precise, and it adds uncecessary complexity without more details. But thanks. :-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Added final code block. Better? :-)

Comment: Almost. I replaced `SetLength()` and `Move()` with a single `SetString()` instead, which also accounts for 0-length files.

Comment: There should be a mention that the last piece of code here assumes pre-Unicode Delphi.

Comment: The code is using `AnsiString`, so it will work in Unicode versions of Delphi as well. But just like in earlier versions, be careful assigning an `AnsiString` to a different string type, like `WideString`, `UnicodeString` or `UTF8String`, because it will perform a data conversion using the OS default codepage, potentially losing data if the `AnsiString` contains non-ASCII characters that can't be represented in that codepage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TFileStream to open the file, specified in the TxtFile.text property
the '#1' is mean to be the file handle but it not neeed because you re using an OOP approach.

Open txtFile.Text For Binary As #1 mean to open the file not in text mode (as opening in the notepad) btu as binary so nothing could be translated to ascii characters. All will be read ad bytes not as characters

LOF(1) seems to return the length of the file (handle 1) and 'Space' will generate a string with the same number of space characters (#32) as the length of the files and assign it to variable 'file', then it will close the file handle.

So as an example:

```
var
    FileContents: AnsiString; // Or an 'array of Byte' instead
    Stream: TFileStream;
begin
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(txtFile.Text, fmOpenRead);
    try
        SetLength(FileContents, Stream.Size);
        if Length(FileContents) > 0 then
            Stream.ReadBuffer(Pointer(FileContents)^, Stream.Size);
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
    // Use FileContents as needed...
end;
```

Disclaimer notice:

- I have not tested it yet; I'm not at my development computer right
  now. So use it on your own risk.
- What you have to determine is if you will read the data as bytes or
  as characters.
- The example assumes you're reading an ANSI text file
- The example assumes you're reading a not so
  large file, if it is large you have to read it in blocks.
- The error handler is just an example how to manage an error
- For more info, check TFileStream (and related classes) usage in the Delphi help documentation.

Comment: -1 for the strange Delphi code (which will not even compile). [Even if it would compile, the error-handling approach is odd.]

Comment: +1 this approach is the most direct equivalent of the original VB Code, but the implementation had errors in it, which I have corrected.

Comment: Shocking rollback to a version containing errors. Remy's edit simply fixed some syntax errors. Was not major problem. More helpful to have Remy's edit.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have never used that kind of task, I just translated as is by intuition, the base code for TFileStream usage was from another site, so i thing the error is there also. I apologize, I will make the compiling tests next time.

Comment: I've opened a thread regarding the revisions and reversions at [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188686/172661). Remy's edit totally revised the code that was posted (which didn't even compile), changing the entire meaning and content of the code.

Comment: @KenWhite Your logic is flawed. The fact that I did not edit your post at that time is irrelevant. The fact that I did not do that does not imply that Remy was in the wrong here. Your edits made this answer worse. We are in the business of helping people. I'm appalled by your edits here. I am deeply unimpressed.

Comment: I have corrected the example thanks, just to clarify I'm not always in my development machine to test the code. The one who post the question only wanted an explanation of "how to translate it", check his last paragraph, and also by looking at his Name maybe english is not his natural language, so don't judge him as "'SO' is not translation service". So he meant only to have a guidance, next time I will do only that and nothing more, if I post code I should stated that as a Pseudo-code or put a disclaimer notice :).

Comment: Looks like you got your answer over on meta

Comment: Argh, Remy's edit should have been kept. This is an answer, not a question, so it's in the general interest for it to be a good one.

Comment: This sort of nonsense makes me question whether or not to carry on here. It's draining and needlessly so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, it was discussed in Meta, where it belongs, instead of leaving comments here.

Comment: @Ken The only thing that's needed here now is an apology to Remy and fduenas for your invalid rollback.

Comment: @Ken I've also restored Remy's version of the code which is better than anything else we've seen. I trust that you will leave this alone.

Comment: @David: What apology is due? I disagreed with an edit that was made and reverted it. You disagreed and put it back. I took it to Meta (politely), where others agreed with the edit. I accepted that and moved on. I made what I thought was a valid decision; it turned out I was wrong. I cleaned up my comments here and moved on. I said or did nothing for which an apology is owed, IMO, and the only one who now has not left this alone appears to be you. If you have further comments regarding this, please take them to Meta where they belong (as I did).

Comment: @Ken You got it wrong, fair enough, a simple sorry makes it right. I've had it with you. I'm out.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I meant no offense when I rolled back your edit. I honestly thought it was against the guidelines here to make that severe an edit to code (I even posted a link to a meta post that said why I thought so). When I was told I was wrong, I asked (politely) at meta to have things clarified, and it was agreed that I was wrong. Please accept my apology for my mistake and any offense it may have caused. I will make every effort not to make that same mistake again in the future.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I apologize for any inadvertent offense I may have caused for Remy by attempting to follow what I thought were the guidelines here. I've admitted I was wrong (twice at meta, and also here). I've also apologized to Remy (see above) directly.

Comment: @KenWhite: no offense taken. I did not even see this little discussion until just now. I understand what happened. No harm done, other than dragging on the comments. Let's just stop here and move on. That is all I will say here.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thank you. And I agree with the "enough is enough" sentiment.